# Identity Server / OIDC - Correct place to store original URL

Tags: openid, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm in the process of setting up Identity Server 4 and one of the things I've been trying to implement is redirecting back to the original requested page when a user is sent to IdentityServer due to the page being 'secured'. Can anybody advise on the correct place to store this information in OIDC?

I assume I need to set a value within the setup doing something like

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options =>
{
 options.Events.RedirectToAuthenticationEndpoint((RedirectContent c) => 
 {
  // Set up something here..
 }
}
```

Comment: If I get your question right, I think web.config is a good place.

Comment: Hi. No, I don't think you have understood. This is a dynamic value defined based on the page the user is visiting, not a static URL

Comment: the event you're handling in your code is only required if you need to do something before you redirect. You don't need to do anything with this event ordinarily.